# Invalid/empty OAuth parameters When Authorizing GADS

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-directory-api

I am trying to configure my LDAP server for GADS for User's management.When I am trying to Configure Google Apps according to the following image,

[image]

I get the following error.

```
[2015-09-02 17:56:40,524] [AWT-EventQueue-0] [WARN] [page.google.GoogleConnectionSettingsPane$AuthorizeAction] Verification failed for OAuth parameters present in config : Invalid/empty OAuth parameters.
[2015-09-02 17:56:40,524] [AWT-EventQueue-0] [TRACE] [usersyncapp.util.ProxyAuthenticator] Overriding default Authenticator.
[2015-09-02 17:56:41,774] [AWT-EventQueue-0] [INFO] [ui.util.OpenUrl] Opening URL :https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?approval_prompt=force&client_id=118556098869.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/calendar/resource/%20https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit&hd=mydomain
```

I have enabled the API access in the admin console. I dont know how to figure out the error. Please help me to figure out the error with configuring GADS.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and called Google Support. Turns out my server time was out of sync. Fixing the time fixed the issue.